# Bitbucket Pipeline schedule trigger

Tags: deployment, yaml, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I can't see anyone talking about what I'm looking to do. I'm currently running a pipeline on a branch merge within the bitbucket area.

```
  branches:
    staging:
      - step:
          name: Clone
          script:
            - echo "Clone all the things!"
```

What I want to do is when a branch gets merged into master, trigger an event that will enable the schedule to run for the next day.

If there are no changes I don't want anything to run, however, if there are I want the schedule to kick in and work.

I've read through the Pipeline triggers:

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/pipeline-triggers/

But I can't see anywhere that would allow me to do it. Has anyone done this sort of thing? Is it possible, or am I limited by bitbucket itself?

Answer (score 1):

Never done this, but there's an API for creating schedules. I think you would need to determine the date and specify the single cron task, e.g. March 30, 2022 at midnight:
0 0 30 3 * 2022

However year is an extension, not a standard CRON field; "at" is an alternative that may be accessible (but also not standard). It all depends on what Bitbucket allows for CRON schedule, so I think this is not a conclusive answer (still needs info on how to setup the schedule).

Here is the docs
https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pipelines_config/schedules/

Answer (score 0):

Things I found after going through bitbucket docs about scheduled trigger :

1. You can use bitbucket's "scheduled pipelines" feature directly from UI where you can provide specific cron for your pipeline (drawback : you can do that for pipelines with no pipeline params only)
2. You can go for there bitbucket's REST API for scheduled pipeline
3. You can simply go for external scheduler like 'crontab' option

Hope this helps!